# Option unicode and beamer with LuaLaTeX

Tags: beamer, hyperref, luatex

In this MWE

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode=true}{hyperref}
\documentclass[xcolor=svgnames]{beamer} 

\title
{
\color{red}Example Presentation Created with the Beamer Package
}
\author{Till Tantau}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\section[Outline]{}
\frame{\tableofcontents}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Overview of the Beamer Class}
\frame
{
  \frametitle{Features of the Beamer Class}

  \begin{itemize}
  \item<1-> Normal LaTeX class.
  \item<2-> Easy overlays.
  \item<3-> No external programs needed.      
  \end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

I know the option `unicode=true` is not necessary. However, when I compile with LuaLaTeX, I have got one error: `Improper alphabetic constant`. Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your color in the title triggers the error. Hide it with `\texorpdfstring`:

```
\title
{
  \texorpdfstring{\color{red}}{}Example Presentation Created with the Beamer Package
}
```

Comment: `@Ulrike Fischer` Perfect!

Answer (score 2):

`beamer` has its own methods to set colours. To modify the title colour it is better to use `\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=red}` instead of messing with the argument of `\title{}`.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode=true}{hyperref}
\documentclass[xcolor=svgnames]{beamer} 

\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=red}

\title{Example Presentation Created with the Beamer Package}
\author{Till Tantau}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

    \frame{\titlepage}

    \section[Outline]{}
    \frame{\tableofcontents}

    \section{Introduction}
    \subsection{Overview of the Beamer Class}
    \frame
    {
        \frametitle{Features of the Beamer Class}

        \begin{itemize}
            \item<1-> Normal LaTeX class.
            \item<2-> Easy overlays.
            \item<3-> No external programs needed.      
        \end{itemize}
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @jpayansomet You're welcome!